# How to analyse pixel data statistics of multiple photos at once for comparison?

Tags: image-processing

I have to analyse multiple photos downloaded to a laptop (approximately 120 photos) taken of a target that has experienced slight environmental changes causing slight variations in pixel values with respect to time.  In particular, I am interested in the grayscale response.

These photos have sequential filenames in the order needed for the analysis already.

What I am in need of a recommendation for, is a program (Windows 7 based or older) that can analyse the grayscale pixel statistics (mean, standard deviation - above a defined threshold value) of multiple photos at once.

Preferably, the program would need to be open source, but I am open to paid versions.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest installing [python](http://python.org) and [numpy](http://numpy.org) and [scipy](http://www.scipy.org) then you can load each image as an array and calculate mean & standard deviation.  Some [examples (see 2.6.3.1)](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/image_processing/) are online.  You can either use a list of files as input or `glob.glob` from the standard libraries.

If you also use the python [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) library you will be able to process several pictures *nearly* simultaneously and with a bit more work, if you need to do this sort of thing regularly, to share the work across several machines.

Python/Numpy/Scipy are all:

- Free
- available from windows XP-8, linux, mac, supercomputers, etc....
- will actually analyze the files one after the other but can easily do so from a single invocation.
- can do a lot more.